# Arc- trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

This is, perhaps, too simple of a question for here, but I'd love it if someone helped me out.

I'm just learning about arc- trigonometric functions (because I failed both calculus exams) and my textbook says that it's pretty obvious how to prove the following equations. However, I've been trying for some time now and I can't seem to get the answers right. (Also, couldn't find the same problem anywhere else)

$$\begin{align*}
\cos^2(\operatorname{arctg}x) &= \frac{1}{1+x^2}\\\\
\operatorname{tg}(\arcsin x) &= \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\\\
\sin(\operatorname{arctg} x) &= \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\\\\
\arcsin x &=\pi/2 - \arccos x
\end{align*}$$

I don't expect an answer to all of those. I suspect that they are very close to one another. If you would just help me out with the ideas, that would be great as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Use that

$$\cos^2(x)=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$$

$$\sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)$$

$$\cos(2x)=\frac{1-\tan^2(x)}{1+\tan^2(x)}$$

and 
$$\tan(x)=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}.$$

Comment: Thanks! I just realized how stupid my question looks (being 2nd year Computer Science, lol)

Comment: Can you give me a tip for the 3rd? I'm stuck at transforming it to cosine.

Comment: Easier, $$\sin^2(\arctan x)=1-\cos^2(\arctan x)=1-\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$$ and thus $$|\sin(\arctan x)|=\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\implies \sin(\arctan x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

For the first demonstration, use the following variable change $y = \arctan x$, so that $x = \tan y$ and 
$$
\cos^2 y = \frac{1}{1 + \tan^2 y}
$$
Next, by direct substitution of $\tan y = \sin y / \cos y$ and $\sin^2 y + \cos^2 y = 1$ you have the proof. I think that using this variable change the others proof can easily be done.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
by definition you have:
$$
\arctan x=y \iff x=\tan y
$$
$$
\arcsin x=y \iff x=\sin y
$$
$$
\arccos x=y \iff x=\cos y
$$

Using this definitions you can solve your equations.  E.g. the first one become:

$$
\cos^2y=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}
$$
 and, since $x=\tan y$

$$
\cos^2y=\dfrac{1}{1+\tan^2 y}
$$
that you can easely verify.

This way is useful for eqautions with inverse trigonometric functions